# How to slow down the flames with simulation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, fire

I want to slow down the speed of flames. I am trying to create smaller flames but slower. Which simulation settings do I need to dial?  I tried smaller simulation time steps but that made it worsts, I think the time steps do not work well with smaller objects.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the "Time Scale" Parameter? [image]

This should change the relation between your simulated time and playback time.

Alternatively, you could run your fluid calculation with a high framerate (eg. 100 or more) and after finishing the calculation, you can set the framerate back to your animation needs, which will effectively slow down the simulation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/130847)

Comment: You're right, I edited the answer to be a bit more "answery"

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I already mentioned it "I tried smaller simulation time steps but that made it worst, I think the time steps do not work well with smaller objects."

Comment: Did you try it? The "Time Steps" setting does something quite different from the "Time Scale": Time steps shouldn't have an actual effect on the speed of the flow but rather on how accurately it is calculated. Time scale on the other hand does actually control the flow speed of the fluid

Answer (score 0):

The simulation is based on physical real world behaviours and so you might br able to get the results you want by simply changing the *scale* of your simulation.

Small flames like candles are naturally fast and flickery as everything is happening over such a small scale. Increase the scale of your fire and the reactions and interactions happen over a much larger scale, taking longer - and so slower.

In Blender you can either set the scale of the scene or use the default 1 Blender Unit = 1 metre. A 10cm flame will react and move much quicker than a 10m flame.

After resizing your emitter mesh and domain, don’t forget to Apply Scale so that Blender recognises its new size.